# OnClickListener in RecyclerView (ImageView)

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, recyclerview-layout

I am trying to do this. In the CardView of a RecyclerView, if you tap on the image, a new activity must open with a bigger version of the image. Like tapping on the image of the profile pic of Whatsapp.

So a I thought I will do it with a OnClicklisterner on the Image.
I get this error message while running it:
error: incompatible types:  cannot be converted to Activity
Some help would really be appreciated, I am still new to Android and Java, and I am a bit stuck. 
Here is the code I've tried so far:

```
         @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewTwoHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.tvBrand.setText((CharSequence) modelTwoArrayList.get(position).getBrand());
    holder.tvImage.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(modelTwoArrayList.get(position).getImage())));
    holder.tvImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, modelTwoArrayList.get(position).getImage());
        Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), DetailsActivity.class);
        view.getContext().startActivity(i, options.toBundle());

        }
    });
```

The position in this line gives me the problem:

```
     ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, modelTwoArrayList.get(position).getImage());
```

Thank you for your time in advance.

My code now:

```
        @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewTwoHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.tvBrand.setText((CharSequence) modelTwoArrayList.get(position).getBrand());
    holder.tvImage.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(modelTwoArrayList.get(position).getImage())));
    holder.tvImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity) ctx, holder.tvImage, "imageAnimation");
        Intent i = new Intent(ctx, DetailsActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("image_url", String.valueOf(holder.tvImage));
        ctx.startActivity(i, options.toBundle());

        }
    });
```

And my DetailsActivity:

```
   public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.details_activity);
    getIncomingIntent();
}

private void getIncomingIntent(){
String imageUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("imageAnimation");
    setImage(imageUrl);
    }

private void setImage(String imageUrl){
    ImageView image = findViewById(R.id.beer_logo);

}}
```

Comment: Try this `ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(view.getContext(), holder.tvImage,"yourSharedElementName");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Make sure that your first parameter `this` is reference of Activity.

2) Make sure that your second parameter `modelTwoArrayList.get(position).getImage()` is ImageView of list. It seems that this is not so. It must be like this `holder.tvImage`

3) Provide third string parameter "imageAnimation"

All in all your code will be look something like this

```
ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(MyActivity.this, holder.tvImage, "imageAnimation");
Intent i = new Intent(MyActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
MyActivity.this.startActivity(i, options.toBundle());
```

Comment: Thank you, I changed my code like that, and now my new activity open, but I still can't seem to make the image show in the DetailsActivity. I now I should have asked a new question, but maybe you can see something.

Answer (score 0):

You are having problem because `ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation` is expecting an `Activity` but when you do `this` you are giving it your Adapter.

To solve the problem change the constructor of your adapter to take the activity in

```
MyAdapter(Context context,Arg1,Arg2){
  this.myActivityContext = context;
  ... other stuffs
}
```

Then when you initialise adapter in your Activity

```
MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this,arg1,arg2)
```

Then

```
ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(myActivityContext, modelTwoArrayList.get(position).getImage());
```